# How to show sum of columns in separate table

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reporting, ssrs-2012

I am developing SSRS report with SQL Server 2014 and have prepared the data for the same. Now I want to display the data as below

[image]

I was able to display the data of first 2 tables which is for Product A and Product B, but the last table is the sum of the above table rows.

So how do I do that in SSRS?

Answer (score 0):

You can use The ReportItem-TextBOX.
Write a expression
where

> ReportItems!Textbox47.Value+ ReportItems!Textbox48.Value
>
> > Here TextBox47 is the Name of the text box you want to get the value from

Assuming that the Place where Column value is to be fetched is usually at a same place [Text Box id to be fetched from here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFyZe.png)